# Django-celery doesn't restore all tasks after restart

Tags: django, message-queue, celery, django-celery

I'm using django ORM as a celery broker, when I schedule tasks and kill celery worker (by hitting ctr+c) before tasks completion, and restart celery again, it doesn't restore all the tasks!! why is that?, I thought django ORM is persistent Broker for celery tasks storage .. what do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually using Django as a broker for celery is the worst thing you can do, as it is very slow and can't restore all the tasks when it is up again after any kind of failure, not sure why, albiet it is using DB to store and keep track of everything.

I used RabbitMQ, it worked like a charm ... faster and more robust and can restore all the tasks when the worker is down and up again.

But still I hope to know why Django ORM is not doing the persistence :)